# PhpStorm: set a specific library version as a project library

Tags: phpstorm, libraries

I am trying to make `JQuery 1.8.3` and `JQuery UI 1.9.2` project libraries in PhpStorm 2017. When I go to *Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> Javascript >> Libraries*, there is a dropdown near the top with two options:

- TypeScript community stubs: here I find simple listings for `jquery` and `jqueryui` with no version information.
- Official Libraries: here I find listings for `jQuery 2.0.0` and `jQuery UI 1.10.2`

[image]

What's the recommended way to get IDE support for the specific versions of these libraries that I intend to use on my project?

#### Update

I have downloaded the uncompressed [`jQuery 1.8.3` file](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/11/13/jquery-1-8-3-released/) and saved it on disk. Then from *Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> JavaScript >> Libraries* I selected `Add...` to link to that custom file and the jQuery documentation.

With @LazyOne's help, I was even able to download what are hopefully the right docs from [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/resources/api.xml). However, the results are mixed:

From good...

[image]

To poor...

[image]

To non-existent...

[image]

To errors...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried downloading local version of the jQuery documentation (not sure about current versions of IDE .. but in previous ones it was possible to have local version when adding Documentation URL -- IDE was downloading and storing that for you (last time I did this for jQuery was over 1 year ago))

Comment: @LazyOne I don't see a way to download it. [this page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2011/04/jquery-offline-doc/) from 2011 suggests that it's possible, but on my UI, the download button is greyed out (look at the bottom right of my 2nd screenshot, near the mouse cursor)

Comment: Try changing to `http` protocol (just as original blog article had) -- download button got enabled for me if I do that: https://postimg.org/image/rb53uzovp/ . This IDE has "issues" in some places when dealing with HTTPS (not bugs .. but rather some kind of "limitations" here and there .. which I personally do not understand)

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. I was able to download, but it didn't do me a whole lot of good. See my update. Feels a bit like swimming upstream at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same results and this looks like a bug. I've tried the same project in 2016.3.3 and it showed me correct documentation while in 2017.2.3 IDE displays 2 identical links that do not work. You might want to report this at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB#newissue=yes. This is also looks like a https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77527 regression

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and certainly for testing an older version!